# Sudo required to run Kubernetes on Ubuntu Server, but not on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, kubernetes, user-permissions

I am wondering why I need sudo to run Kubernetes on Ubuntu Server, but not on Ubuntu Desktop. Installed kubectl:kubectl, minikube and docker.io on both an Ubuntu Server 18.04 and on an Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 box. The installation procedure and versions where the same on both. I now get the following on the server:

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1029 18:31:32.407952     715 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Saving driver.
: mkdir /home/eric/.minikube/machines/minikube: permission denied.

 Retrying.
E1029 18:31:32.408426     715 start.go:174] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Saving driver.
: mkdir /home/eric/.minikube/machines/minikube: permission denied
```

It works on the desktop. Is the user model / permissions different on the server?

Comment: What groups is your user in, on each machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare permissions for your /home/eric/.minikube directory on desktop and server installations and list of groups your user belongs to.

It could be different directory permissions or just membership in specific group is required.